# How do I get the IE6 upgrade page to display to IE7 users?

Tags: joomla, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am using Joomla 1.7 with a Yootheme template. There is an option to display an 'Upgrade Your Browser' page to IE6 users, I want to display it to IE7 users as well. How would I modify this code to do it?

```
public function isIE6() {
    if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie' && $this['useragent']->version() == '6.0') {
    if ($this->get('forwardie6') !== null) {
    $this->cookie('WarpForwardie6', (int) $this->get('forwardie6') == 0 ? 'no' : 'yes');
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: there are other "behind the scene" codes... but basically you need to add another condition "else if" and change the version() to '7.0' but the rest of the code needs deeper analyzing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon there are no other functions related to IE6 so ...

I'd simply change

```
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie' && $this['useragent']->version() == '6.0') {
```

into

```
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie' && ($this['useragent']->version() == '6.0' || $this['useragent']->version() == '7.0' )) {
```

I don't expect any further issues related to forcing IE7 to be treated as IE6

Comment: In that case, you may as well rename the function to isOldIE() and use a number parse and a less than instead of two string comparisons.  Then you cover IE5 as well :)

Comment: Why would you rename the function that can be used in many places? I completely agree about including IE5 into the scope, whatmore... for users of IE4 and lower I'd expand the function with exit();  :]

Answer (score 0):

I would just change this -

```
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie' && $this['useragent']->version() == '6.0') {
```

To this -

```
if ($this['useragent']->browser() == 'msie' && int($this['useragent']->version()) < 8) {
```

This should work for any version of IE older than IE 8.